# Union Query picking up table names dynamically

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

1. I am using MS ACCESS to automate a system.
2. There are 52 week files per year and data is for a period of 3 years, i.e 156 files named [Week 1], [Week 2],...... Total number of records is close to 60 lakhs. Columns number upto 60
3. I tried to create a union of all the 156 but got an error "System Resource Exceeded"

I want to know if it is possible to make a union dynamic. i.e. I will have a master table containing 6 fields (*table names which I will input manually*) like [Week 1], [Week 6], [Week 89], [Week 98], [Week 75], [Week 152]. The union query I must create will automatically pick up table names from the master table and create the union.

- WHAT I WANT:

  ```
  select * from [Field 1 from Master table];
  UNION
  select * from [Field 2 from Master table];
  UNION
  select * from [Field 3 from Master table];
  UNION
  select * from [Field 4 from Master table];
  UNION
  select * from [Field 5 from Master table];
  UNION
  select * from [Field 6 from Master table];
  ```

  1. is it possible in MS ACCESS?

Comment: Can any one please help me out?

Comment: I think you need to ask: To what end? Is the amount of data simply going to continue to increase with no purging or obsolescence? If you're not AT the limits of Access, you are likely very close to them as it is. I'd recommend up-sizing to MS SQL Server and work with Partitioned tables rather than files separately. This project sounds like it's well outgrown Access.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have a separate table for each week? From the fact you are trying to `UNION` them I gather that they all have the same fields. Would you not be better off with all the data in one table?

Comment: not able to perform the union. That is the problem right now!!! Weekly data comes every week. Total records will be at max 60 lakhs when project terminates.